# Is there a simpler way to express "turn out to be" in this context?

Tags: word-meaning

> My brand new car **turned out to be** a piece of junk.

How do you simplify "turn out to be" and "junk" in simple easy English?

I know how to use a dictionary, but I need to teach this to my mother and I need to gain some exprience doing that in working order.

Answer (score 1):

Again, there could be various versions, I'm simplifying it my way.

You may simply say...

> It is my new car but it is not working properly.

That's because *turned out to be...* is the phrase you use when you expect something but ultimately get something else (in this case, exactly opposite).

You bought a new car and you expect it to work fine without giving any problem. But, it is waste as it's not functioning properly.

Comment: I think it's not always the case that *a piece of junk* would mean "not working properly".

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce it to

> My brand new car is a lemon.

A *lemon*, when used as a description of a product (especially a car), means that the product is severely flawed, possibly to the point of uselessness.  (see wikipedia's [Lemon (car) definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemon_%28automobile%29).)

As MaulikV notes, "turned out to be" is a phrase you can use when you have an expectation about something, but the actual result is something else.  Since the idea of "brand new" carries with it naturally the connotations of quality and desirability, while "lemon" provides the exact opposite (defectiveness and undesirability), the contrast is already provided in the nouns, and doesn't need additional attention called to it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straightforward simplification:

> *My brand new car turned out to be a piece of junk.*
>   (= My brand new car is very **[disappointing](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/disappointing)**.)

If you want to simplify only the part "turned out to be", you could use "is" (or "was", depending your context; I will assume that you want to use "is"). It might be a little different from the original, but it will keep the general idea intact.

> *My brand new car turned out to be a piece of junk.*
>   (= My brand new car **is** a piece of junk.)

If you want to simplify only the part "a piece of junk", you could use "useless". (Actually, I thought of a few other words, which I think might not be appropriate. One of them begins with *s*; another begins with *c*. *Useless* is much safer.) Again, this might be a little different from the original, but it should convey roughly the same idea.

> *My brand new car turned out to be a piece of junk.*
>   (= My brand new car turned out to be **useless**.)